# how to avoid to match the last letter in this regexp?

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a quesion about regexp in tcl:

```
first output: TIP_12.3.4 %
second output: TIP_12.3.4 %
```

and sometimes the output maybe look like:

```
first output: TIP_12 %
second output: TIP_12 %
```

I want to get the number 12.3.4 or 12 using the following exgexp:

```
output: TIP_(/[0-9].*/[0-9])
```

but why it does not matches 12.3.4 or 12%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `/` is not special in Tcl's regular expression language *at all*. It's just an ordinary printable non-letter character. (Other languages are a little different, as it is quite common to enclose regular expressions in `/` characters; this is not the case in Tcl.) Because it is a simple literal, using it in your RE makes it expect it in the input (despite it not being there); unsurprisingly, that makes the RE not match.

Fixing things: I'd use a regular expression like this: `output: TIP_([\d.]+)` under the assumption that the data is reasonably well formatted. That would lead to code like this:

```
regexp {output: TIP_([0-9.]+)} $input -> dottedDigits
```

Everything not in parentheses is a literal here, so that the code is able to find what to match. Inside the parentheses (the bit we're saving for later) we want one or more digits or periods; putting them inside a square-bracketed-set is perfect and simple. The net effect is to store the `12.3.4` in the variable `dottedDigits` (if found) and to yield a boolean *result* that says whether it matched (i.e., you can put it in an `if` condition usefully).

**NB:** the regular expression is enclosed in braces because square brackets are *also* Tcl language metacharacters; putting the RE in braces avoids trouble with misinterpretation of your script. (You could use backslashes instead, but they're *ugly*…)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the dot, else it stands for "match every character". Also, I'm not sure about the slashes in your regexp. Better solution:

```
/TIP_(\d+\.?)+/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
output: TIP_(/([0-9\.^%]*)/[0-9])
```

Capture group 1.

Demo here :

http://regexr.com?31f6g

Answer (score 0):

The following expression works for me:

```
{TIP_((\d+\.?)+)}
```